# How to deserialize a large JSON with multiple tags, received in an API call

Tags: vb.net, json.net

I am receiving a large block of `JSON` information from an API call.
This example lists 2 of the items received; normally, this list will contain hundreds.

The `JSON` received is:

```
{
"data":[
        {
         "id":"2324682","type":"organizations","attributes":
        {
         "psa-integration":null,
         "name":"Client1",
         "alert":null,
         "description":null,
         "organization-type-id":null,
         "organization-type-name":null,
         "organization-status-id":null,
         "organization-status-name":null,
         "my-glue-account-id":null,
         "primary":true,
         "quick-notes":null,
         "short-name":"P",
         "created-at":"2017-09-25T17:21:26.000Z",
         "updated-at":"2018-02-09T17:25:34.000Z",
         "my-glue-account-status":null,
         "logo":"client1.jpg"
         },"relationships":{"adapters-resources":{"data":[]}}},
    {
      "id":"2388378","type":"organizations","attributes":
        {
         "psa-integration":null,
         "name":"Client2",
         "alert":null,
         "description":null,
         "organization-type-id":53460,
         "organization-type-name":"E123",
         "organization-status-id":17054,
         "organization-status-name":"Active",
         "my-glue-account-id":null,
         "primary":false,
         "quick-notes":null,
         "short-name":null,
         "created-at":"2017-10-16T19:36:30.000Z",
         "updated-at":"2018-08-21T19:06:47.000Z",
         "my-glue-account-status":null,
         "logo":"client2.jpg"
          },"relationships":{"adapters-resources":{"data":[]}}}],
"meta":
     {
      "current-page":1,
      "next-page":2,
      "prev-page":null,
      "total-pages":16,
      "total-count":31,
      "filters":
       {
        "id":{"permitted-values":[]},
        "name":{"permitted-values":[]},
        "organization-type-id":{"permitted-values": 
[{"value":39230,"data":{"name":"client"}},{"value":39231,"data":    {"name":"CLient2"}},{"value":39232,"data":{"name":"Internal"}},    {"value":39233,"data":{"name":"Other"}},{"value":39234,"data":{"name":"Partner"}},{"value":39235,"data":{"name":"Prospect"}},{"value":39236,"data":{"name":"Vendor"}},{"value":53460,"data":{"name":"newname"}}]},"organization-status-id":{"permitted-values":[{"value":17054,"data":{"name":"Active"}},{"value":17055,"data":{"name":"Inactive"}}]},"created-at":{"permitted-values":[]},"updated-at":{"permitted-values":[]},"my-glue-account-id":{"permitted-values":[]}}},"links":{"self":"https://api.itglue.com/organizations?page%5Bnumber%5D=1\u0026page%5Bsize%5D=2\u0026sort=id","next":"https://api.itglue.com/organizations?page%5Bnumber%5D=2\u0026page%5Bsize%5D=2\u0026sort=id","last":"https://api.itglue.com/organizations?page%5Bnumber%5D=16\u0026page%5Bsize%5D=2\u0026sort=id"}}
```

So far I have tried creating classes for the data, but it seems to give me no information.

In order to process the data, I had to change all the properties names, because many contain a dash:
For example, **`Created-at`** is now **`Created_at`**

I used [`jsonutils.com`](http://jsonutils.com/) to create the VB.Net classes.

I load the `JSON` into a string called **`Change_String`**.

If anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong, I would appreciate it

```
Dim changed_string as string = "JSON INPUT _ instead of -"   
Dim obj As Attributes
obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Attributes)(changed_string)
msgbox(obj.name)
```

Classes:

```
Public Class Attributes
    Public Property psa_integration As Object
    Public Property name As String
    Public Property alert As Object
    Public Property description As Object
    Public Property organization_type_id As Integer?
    Public Property organization_type_name As String
    Public Property organization_status_id As Integer?
    Public Property organization_status_name As String
    Public Property my_glue_account_id As Object
    Public Property primary As Boolean
    Public Property quick_notes As String
    Public Property short_name As String
    Public Property created_at As String
    Public Property updated_at As String
    Public Property my_glue_account_status As Object
    Public Property logo As String
End Class

Public Class AdaptersResources
    Public Property data As Object()
End Class

Public Class Relationships
    Public Property adapters_resources As AdaptersResources
End Class

Public Class Datum
    Public Property id As String
    Public Property type As String
    Public Property attributes As Attributes
    Public Property relationships As Relationships
End Class

Public Class Id
    Public Property permitted_values As Object()
End Class

Public Class Name
    Public Property permitted_values As Object()
End Class

Public Class Data
    Public Property name As String
End Class

Public Class PermittedValue
    Public Property value As Integer
    Public Property data As Data
End Class

Public Class OrganizationTypeId
    Public Property permitted_values As PermittedValue()
End Class

Public Class OrganizationStatusId
    Public Property permitted_values As PermittedValue()
End Class

Public Class CreatedAt
    Public Property permitted_values As Object()
End Class

Public Class UpdatedAt
    Public Property permitted_values As Object()
End Class

Public Class MyGlueAccountId
    Public Property permitted_values As Object()
End Class

Public Class Filters
    Public Property id As Id
    Public Property name As Name
    Public Property organization_type_id As OrganizationTypeId
    Public Property organization_status_id As OrganizationStatusId
    Public Property created_at As CreatedAt
    Public Property updated_at As UpdatedAt
    Public Property my_glue_account_id As MyGlueAccountId
End Class

Public Class Meta
    Public Property current_page As Integer
    Public Property next_page As Object
    Public Property prev_page As Object
    Public Property total_pages As Integer
    Public Property total_count As Integer
    Public Property filters As Filters
End Class

Public Class Links
End Class

Public Class Organizations
    Public Property data As Datum()
    Public Property meta As Meta
    Public Property links As Links
End Class
```

Comment: show us `classes` to.

Comment: Added Classes to original post

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54566456/how-to-deserialize-a-large-json-file-with-multiple-tags-that-were-received-in-an In particular, this: http://jsonutils.com/

Comment: That is what I use to create the classes, It works fast.

Comment: It looks like the `RootObject` is the class named `Organizations`, here. If you want to change the name of the properties, use a `<JsonProperty> `. For example `<JsonProperty("psa-integration")> Public Property PsaIntegration As Object`

Comment: I think You have to rewrite, manually write, classes, and problem is about that `-` and `_`... in your source are still `-`.

Comment: I just saw `jsonutils.com`. It provides the option to add JSON Attributes to the property names. You don't need to do anything manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I gave it a second look.
The classes generated by the online service are not exactly spectacular.

This is a modified class structure that should provide the correct results.
I compacted everything in a single class named **`JSON_Organizations`**, which contains all the classes needed by the JSON deserializer.

All the properties are renamed using [JSON Attributes](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationAttributes.htm), so the bad names are taken care of.

Sample converter:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Dim JSONObject As String = "[The JSON Object]"

Dim Organizations As JSON_Organizations.RootObject = New JSON_Organizations.RootObject
Organizations = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of JSON_Organizations.RootObject)(JSONObject)
```

The **`JSON_Organizations`** container class:

```
Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Class JSON_Organizations

    Public Class RootObject

        <JsonProperty("data")>
        Public Property Data As Datum()

        <JsonProperty("meta")>
        Public Property Meta As Meta

        <JsonProperty("links")>
        Public Property Links As Links
    End Class

    Public Class Datum

        <JsonProperty("id")>
        Public Property Id As String

        <JsonProperty("type")>
        Public Property Type As String

        <JsonProperty("attributes")>
        Public Property Attributes As Attributes

        <JsonProperty("relationships")>
        Public Property Relationships As Relationships
    End Class

    Public Class Attributes

        <JsonProperty("psa-integration")>
        Public Property PsaIntegration As Object

        <JsonProperty("name")>
        Public Property Name As String

        <JsonProperty("alert")>
        Public Property Alert As Object

        <JsonProperty("description")>
        Public Property Description As Object

        <JsonProperty("organization-type-id")>
        Public Property OrganizationTypeId As Integer?

        <JsonProperty("organization-type-name")>
        Public Property OrganizationTypeName As String

        <JsonProperty("organization-status-id")>
        Public Property OrganizationStatusId As Integer?

        <JsonProperty("organization-status-name")>
        Public Property OrganizationStatusName As String

        <JsonProperty("my-glue-account-id")>
        Public Property MyGlueAccountId As Object

        <JsonProperty("primary")>
        Public Property Primary As Boolean

        <JsonProperty("quick-notes")>
        Public Property QuickNotes As Object

        <JsonProperty("short-name")>
        Public Property ShortName As String

        <JsonProperty("created-at")>
        Public Property CreatedAt As DateTimeOffset

        <JsonProperty("updated-at")>
        Public Property UpdatedAt As DateTimeOffset

        <JsonProperty("my-glue-account-status")>
        Public Property MyGlueAccountStatus As Object

        <JsonProperty("logo")>
        Public Property Logo As String
    End Class

    Public Class Relationships

        <JsonProperty("adapters-resources")>
        Public Property AdaptersResources As AdaptersResources
    End Class

    Public Class AdaptersResources

        <JsonProperty("data")>
        Public Property Data As List(Of Object)
    End Class

    Public Class Links

        <JsonProperty("self")>
        Public Property Self As String

        <JsonProperty("next")>
        Public Property NextLink As String

        <JsonProperty("last")>
        Public Property Last As String
    End Class

    Public Class Meta

        <JsonProperty("current-page")>
        Public Property CurrentPage As Long

        <JsonProperty("next-page")>
        Public Property NextPage As Long

        <JsonProperty("prev-page")>
        Public Property PrevPage As Object

        <JsonProperty("total-pages")>
        Public Property TotalPages As Long

        <JsonProperty("total-count")>
        Public Property TotalCount As Long

        <JsonProperty("filters")>
        Public Property Filters As Filters
    End Class

    Public Class Filters

        <JsonProperty("id")>
        Public Property Id As CreatedAt

        <JsonProperty("name")>
        Public Property Name As CreatedAt

        <JsonProperty("organization-type-id")>
        Public Property OrganizationTypeId As CreatedAt

        <JsonProperty("organization-status-id")>
        Public Property OrganizationStatusId As CreatedAt

        <JsonProperty("created-at")>
        Public Property CreatedAt As CreatedAt

        <JsonProperty("updated-at")>
        Public Property UpdatedAt As CreatedAt

        <JsonProperty("my-glue-account-id")>
        Public Property MyGlueAccountId As CreatedAt
    End Class

    Public Class CreatedAt

        <JsonProperty("permitted-values")>
        Public Property PermittedValues As List(Of PermittedValue)
    End Class

    Public Class PermittedValue

        <JsonProperty("value")>
        Public Property Value As Integer

        <JsonProperty("data")>
        Public Property Data As Data
    End Class

    Public Class Data
        <JsonProperty("name")>
        Public Property Name As String
    End Class
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you Jimi, I will be able to try this in about an hour,  Thank you for your help

Comment: Jimi, This worked perfect, And I think I actually understand how it works witch is even more important.  I am sure I will have more questions in the future hopefully I can help someone else the way you helped me.

Comment: You're welcome :) BTW, both Visual Studio and `jsonutils.com` make the same mistake in converting the JSON to classes. For future reference, use this Site: [QuickType](https://app.quicktype.io/#l=cs&r=json2csharp). It doesn't have a VB.Net converter, but it's not really necessary, you just need to compare the classes it generates to what other parsers (or you, manually) do. It's more *professional* an it usually gets it right.